# OpenGL - How to transform a subset of a vertex in a vertex buffer?

Tags: opengl, transformation, vertex-buffer

```
float linePos[6]={0.0f,5.0f,0.0f,0.0f,30.0f,0.0f};    
...

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*2, linePos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

...
glUniformMatrix4fv(UniformColor.modelToWorldMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));
//this just transforms all vertices

glLineWidth(3);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,2);
```

I want to make some animation changing the position (ex.translate) of one end the line(linePos[0]) but not the other. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically 2 options:
Update vertex position in the linePos array and re-upload into the vertex buffer object.You can use [glBufferSubData](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) to update the data.Second ,and by my opinion is better (faster) approach to transform your line in vertex shader.Anyways , if you need to modify individual vertex position the first approach is what you need.Here is a [popular tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2003.html) on how it is done using programmable pipeline.

Btw , I want to extend on shader based solution.I suggested it because your line has only 2 points:start and end.So changing position of any of them is like transforming the whole line by a matrix.That is why I think it is better to do it inside a vertex shader.If you had a line defined by at least 3 vectors , then to modify position of a specific vertex would requre modifying vertex array on CPU .Well,you can do it in geometry shader but this is advanced stuff.

Comment: I understand your first option. Could you clarify the second one?

Comment: Do you use shaders? If no it is hard to explain it all here.But I suggest you reading the tutorial I mentioned in the answer.In its second part the author explains how to move triangle via vertex shader and not by vertex array upload.That is exactly your case.

Comment: The OP is using vertex shader to translate the lines, but he wants to translate only one end of it.

Comment: he can build rotation matrix with lookAt() (see GLM lib) method and pass it to the vertex shader.But yes, if you don't want doing any math then re-uploading vertex buffer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In your vertex shader check if [gl_VertexID](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_VertexID.xml) is odd or even and depending on that you can decide to apply the transformation or not.

Comment: There is also atomic counter for the GL  4.0